# Функция не пересчитывает автоматически

Tags: google-apps-script

```js
function getBackgroundColor(rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification).getBackgroundColor();
}

function sumWhereBackgroundColorIs(color, rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j);
      if(cell.getBackgroundColor() == color)
        x += parseFloat(cell.getValue());
    }
  }
  return x;
}

function onOpen(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Refresh",
    functionName : "refreshLastUpdate"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Refresh", entries);
};

function refreshLastUpdate() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('A70').setValue(new Date().toTimeString());
}



function onChange(e){ 
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  
}




function countCellsWithBackgroundColor(color, rangeSpecification) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);
  var x = 0;
  for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) 
  {
    for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) 
    {
      var cell = range.getCell(i, j).getBackground();      
      if (cell == color) 
      { x++; }
    }
  }
  return x;
  
 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]написала скрипт который считает количество ячеек определенного цвета в заданном диапазоне. Если я меняю количество ячеек заданного цвета , то функция не пересчитывает количество ячеек автоматически . Как сделать , что бы функция пересчитывала автоматически ?

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq212.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день. Представьте, пожалуйста, код вашего скрипта - и тогда мы, возможно, сможем помочь.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Подскажите, а как Вы применяете эту функцию в таблице? Вводите как формулу? Или запускаете из меню? Куда выводится результат?

Comment: Ввожу как формулу  в определенную ячейку=countCellsWithBackgroundColor("#ffff00"; "OU4:OU100"; " "; "OU4:OU100")

Comment: Так. Сразу огромная просьба - не выкладывать код скриншотом - а текстом - чтобы мы могли его скопировать себе и пробовать. А так - мне придется вручную его набивать. А время на такое тратить не хочется.

Comment: А так - Вы передаете в скрипт 2 текста - текст "код цвета" и текст "адрес диапазона". C чего, как Вы думаете, функция должна пересчитывать значения? То есть поменяв цвета в самом файле - 2 текста, которые вы посылаете своей функции не меняются. Поэтому и функция не пересчитывается.

Comment: Так как код Ваш я себе скопировать не смог (он нарисован на картинке) - попробуйте на триггере onEdit(e) поставить SpreadsheetApp.flush()

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо повесить вызов вашей функции на триггер *"изменение данных в таблице"* onEdit(e).

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

G-Apps-Script.COM

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
Добавила onChange(), не работает

Comment: **onChange()** - такого простого триггера нет.

Если все же хотите использовать функцию с таким название, то вам нужно повесить ее на триггер .

Но лучше использовать простой триггер **onEdit()** - он срабатывает при изменении данных в таблице.